# Are there any integer solutions to $2^x+1=3^y$ for $y>2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

for what values of $ x $ and $ y $ the equality holds

> $2^x+1=3^y$

It is quiet obvious the equality holds for $x=1,y=1$ and $x=3,y=2$.
But further I cannot find why $x$ and $y$ cannot take higher values than this values.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29926/3n-2m-pm-41-is-not-possible-how-to-prove-it/29928#29928

Answer (score 10):

Note that $2\equiv -1$ mod $3$, which means that $x$ must be odd.

If $y$ is even, let $y=2z$ and we have $2^x=(3^z+1)(3^z-1)$ with some minor arranging. The two factors on the right-hand side differ by $2$, and must both be powers of $2$, so they must be $2$ and $4$ and $z=1$ which gives us the solution $x=3, y=2$.

It remains to deal with the case in which $x,y$ are both odd. We note that $3\equiv -1$ mod $4$ so if $x \ge 2$ and $y$ is odd the equation becomes $0+1\equiv -1$ mod $4$. So we must have $x\lt 2$ hence $x=1, y=1$.

Answer (score 3):

As the title says "number theory", I am assuming you are looking for *integer* solutions (Otherwise, it is quite obvious that for any $x$ there is a $y$, which solves this).

Then, this is a special case of the (recently proven) [Catalan's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture), which more generally asserts, that 
$$a^x+1=b^y\quad x,y>1$$
has the unique integer solution $a=2,x=3,b=3,y=2$.

So there are only the two solutions you found.

---

Catalan's conjecture is of course a knockout argument. Since your question is only a special case, the problem becomes easier and can be solved my elementary number theory. Check, the other excellent answers for a more direct solution.

Comment: @tomas..but why it doesnt take any values more than it can you say ???????

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. _Why am I saying that there are no more solutions?_ Well, that's what the conjecture is about. Check the link. _Why are there no more solutions?_ This I can't explain, read Mihăilescu's proof, which is way beyond my capabilites...

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that $x$ and $y$ are supposed to be integers.

The claim follows from the fact that if $x>3$, then the order of the residue class of $3$ in the group $\mathbb{Z}_{2^x}^*$ (sometimes denoted by $U_{2^x}$)
is $2^{x-2}$. In other words: for $3^y-1$ to be divisible by $2^x$ the exponent $y$ has to be a multiple of $2^{x-2}$. There are several proofs for this fact in this site.

But when $y\ge 2^{x-2}$, then it shouldn't be too hard to see that $$3^y\ge3^{2^{x-2}}>2^x.$$

Comment: Here $x\ge4$, so $2^{x-2}\ge x$, and thus $$3^{2^{x-2}}\ge 3^x>2^x.$$

Answer (score 0):

With $y \gt 2$, there are only $684$ possible values of $3^y - 2^x$ mod $(262143 = 2^{18} - 1)$, so it is reduced the the finite problem of checking that none of them are $1$.